# Check if array contains at least one element - Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, element, ngfor

I have an array of elements (named "nodes" in my case) and I am loading them inside a table.

That table has a fixed number of columns and rows are generated according to number of nodes I have in that array. Example:

```
<div *ngFor="let node of nodes">
```

Inside every node I have these element properties as you can see from the picture:

[![JSON response][1]][1]

Every node has a `ScopeOfWork` array but some can be empty and some can have elements.

What I need is to check if at least one node has elements inside its `ScopeOfWork` and if there is, then I would like to generate a different table with a different layout.

I need that because I need to implement additional columns that will show me values for that `ScopeOfWork`'s elements (name,type..etc).
If SOW in nodes are empty arrays, then it should generate different table.

Is there posibility to set that check beside this `*ngFor`?

Something like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let node of nodes && (check nodes.SOW-s for any element in their array)">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a function that evaluates that condition using `array#some` ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)):

```
checkIfScopeOfWork() {
  return this.nodes.some(item => item.scopesOfWork.length > 0);
}
```

and use it in your HTML inside an `*ngIf`:

```
<div *ngIf="checkIfScopeOfWork()">
    <div *ngFor="let node of nodes">
   ...
<div *ngIf="!checkIfScopeOfWork()">
  ...something else....
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular doesn't support more than one structural directive in one element ,try ng-container to host your structural directive like this:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let node of nodes">
  <div *ngIf="node.scopesOfWork.length > 0">
     ...
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Tried, but it won't work ...scopesOfWork undefined ...just like you metioned. Thanks :)